# For very large values of $x$, the graph of $f(x) = x^2 / (x + 1)$ behaves as that of a line $y = mx + b$. Find $m$ and $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A friend shared with me this problem and I'm not quite sure if I'm understanding it correctly. If the parabola behaves like a line, wouldn't it just be where they intersect? Graphing it we can see its $y=x-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{x+1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}x-1$$

Observe that $$\frac{x^2}{x+1}=\frac{x^2-1+1}{x+1}=\frac{x^2-1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x+1}=x-1+\frac{1}{x+1}$$

So, since $\frac{x^2}{x+1}=x-1+\frac{1}{x+1}$, we have that: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{x+1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-1+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-1\right)+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x+1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-1\right)$$

which is what we wanted to show.

Edit:

The algebra way to think about this is to recognize the that $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x+1}$ is a rational function with $\deg(\text{numerator})=\deg(\text{denominator})+1$, hence we recognize that there exists an oblique asymptote to the rational function. This oblique asymptote is just the quotient of $$\frac{x^2}{x+1}$$ which can be obtained by polynomial long division.

More information about oblique asymptotes can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Oblique_asymptotes).

Comment: Is it possible to do it without limits? This is my confusion because my friend isn't taking calculus, it's just an honors algebra class.

Comment: I take it back you answered my question, algebraically! The limits are unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks. When dividing, I forgot to divide $-x$ by $x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2=((x+1)-1)^2=$

$(x+1)^2-2(x+1)+1;$

$y=\dfrac{x^2}{x+1}= (x+1)-2 +\dfrac{1}{x+1};$

For large $x$ : $\dfrac{1}{x+1} \rightarrow 0.$

Hence for large $x:$

$y=x-1;$